# Laravel convert one model instance to collection

Tags: php, collections, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I'm trying to remove files from a user within a job::

```
public function handle()
{
    //Remove all files from a message
    $this->files->map(function($file) {
        $path = $file->getPath();

        if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists($path))
        {
            Storage::disk('s3')->delete($path);
            if(!Storage::disk('s3')->exists($path))
            {
                $attachment = File::find($file->id);
                $attachment->delete();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So this is working for `collections`. But how do I get this to work when I pass `one` model instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as the algorithm you want apply to the collection's elements or the Eloquent model is the same, move it in a private method as follows:

```
private _removeFilesFromMessage($file) {
    $path = $file->getPath();

    if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists($path))
    {
        Storage::disk('s3')->delete($path);
        if(!Storage::disk('s3')->exists($path))
        {
            $attachment = File::find($file->id);
            $attachment->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Then modify the handle method like this:

```
public function handle()
{
    if($this->files instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection) {
        //Remove all files from a message
        $this->files->map($this->_removeFilesFromMessage($file));
    } else {
        $this->_removeFilesFromMessage($this->files);
    }
}
```

What are we doing here? We're checking if the $this->files instance is an Eloquent Collection and, in case the condition is true, we use the _removeFilesFromMessage as a callback for the map method. Otherwise (I am assuming that the $this->files contains an Eloquent Model instance) the _removeFilesFromMessage method is called and the model is passed.

I think this code is a good start for your needings.

**edit**

As the title of this question is partially different from what you have asked... for a matter of completion:

You can create Laravel Collections with the collect() method, as described in the [Laravel 5.3 official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#introduction)

Answer (score 8):

You can make it possible in different ways. You can check if `$this->filies`

```
if($this->files instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection) {
  //so its a collection of files
} else {
  //its a one model instance
//here you can do hack, 
  $this->files = collect([$this->files]);
  //and code will works like a magic
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can just check if `$this->files`
 
`if(! ($this->files instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)) {
  $this->files = collect([$this->files]);
}`